# How to include music within .exe file?

Tags: c#, wpf, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use DLL resources for WPF MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827267/use-dll-resources-for-wpf-mediaplayer)

I have a folder named `Sounds`, which contains a music file named `theme.mp3`. This folder is at the root folder of the project.

I would like to include this file directly in the `.exe` file.

For the moment, I can only read music from an external folder.
How do I include the music file within my `.exe` ?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: The general answer is "add it as a resource, then modify your program to read the file as a resource".  HOWEVER - there might be limitations reading an .mp3 from your WPF program.  See this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827267/use-dll-resources-for-wpf-mediaplayer

Answer (score 3):

You can [embedded it as an resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950960.aspx) than read as a stream and play. Or retrieve and store in temp folder and play as previously.

Answer (score 2):

Add `theme.mp3` to your project (Project -> Add Existing Item). Then set that project item's Build Action to "Embedded Resource".

Then at runtime, you can read the MP3 stream via the [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kx66y1a%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method. The [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method may help you discover what the name of your embedded file is known by at runtime.

Comment: I get an XAML parse error as soon as I try to add the file as "Embedded Resource"

Comment: Wow. WPF really shouldn't be trying to read *every* embedded resource in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the project -> property -> resource -> add file