# C# install files

Tags: c#

I want to make a program in C# that when my friends start it starts to hear rick roll I found a way to play the song but they have to install it on their computer to be able to play it. How could I make it to install a rick roll

Comment: does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework

Comment: Just FYI: The song is actually called "Never gonna give you up". The artist's name is Rick Astley (hence "Rick Rolling").

Comment: Does this help? [How to write a simple C# installer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include music within .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190405/how-to-include-music-within-exe-file)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Donno how to install a rickroll but you can open the browser and play it:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
```

Put this in the init.

Comment: i already did that one time but the just paused it

Comment: Well then you should download the mp3 file add it as a resource on a forms application, start playing the file and open a new form with the mp3 file playing again every time they try to close the program, would that work?