# Video not playing in wpf when referenced from folder within project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, video, playback

I'm trying to import short videos into a WPF application. I was having trouble with referencing video from a folder within my project so went back and tried this tutorial.

[Creating a complete audio player link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/how-to-creating-a-complete-audio-video-player/)

From the snippet below you can see what I have been trying to replace the original  code with. I know the line I added will work as it's used elsewhere successfully.

Why can't I load a video from a Resource folder I created but I can load images?

To confirm the video is set to a resource.

```
        private void Open_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        //openFileDialog.Filter = "Media files (*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg)|*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        //if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        //mePlayer.Source = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName); 
        mePlayer.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/videotest;component/Resource/testvideo.mpeg");
    }
```

Comment: Is `P4 Phase 1B LabLog` a valid assembly name?

Comment: @Clemens my mistake uploaded an other URI link. But yes this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't I load a video from a Resource folder I created but I can load images?

Because media files can't be embedded resources. This is because the media player in Windows doesn't understand pack URI:s. The path must be a relative or absolute system path or an URL.

Please refer to the following link for more information.

[Use DLL resources for WPF MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827267/use-dll-resources-for-wpf-mediaplayer)